# RPC failed; curl 18 HTTP/2 stream 5 was reseterror: 7142 bytes of body are still expected fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband

Tags: git, url, clone

RPC failed; curl 18 HTTP/2 stream 5 was reseterror: 7142 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

While I am trying to clone a repository from github using git clone , I am receiving this error

RPC failed; curl 18 HTTP/2 stream 5 was reseterror: 7142 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Can anyone help me get rid of this problem?

Comment: *unexpected disconnect* indicates to me that there was a network issue. Try again.

Comment: Definitely something with the network, and probably a timeout, though there isn't enough information to tell whether it was your client, GitHub, or something in between.